# Not sure how to display backend data in react app

Tags: json, reactjs, backend

I have data that shows up as following in my backend server-

[image]

I want to show this data as frontend.
I did it the following way-

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  useEffect( () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/lang")
    .then(res =>  res.json())
    .then( res => {setData(res)} )
    console.log('datas')
    console.log(data)
  }, [] )
  return (
    <div className="App">
        {
        data.map((data,i) => {
        <h1>
          Edit {data.name} and save to reload.
        </h1>
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This data is being console logged in the background, but it won't show up in the frontend app.

[image]

How would I have the backend data display here?

Comment: First you need to return the element to be displayed and second you used the same name in the map function and for your state, it can cause bug and it's also confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either return the element

```
 data.map((data,i) => {
   return (
    <h1>
      Edit {data.name} and save to reload.
    </h1>
   )
 })
```

Or use parentheses

```
data.map((data,i) => (
  <h1>
    Edit {data.name} and save to reload.
  </h1>
));
```